# Control's Enabled appearance at design time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, design-time, appearance

I defined a custom button class, which sets background color when button is enabled/disabled.

Enabled appearance at runtime (A):

[image]

Disabled appearance at runtime (B):

[image]

Design time appearance is always (A), regardless of the value of `Enabled` property.

I would like my control to appear in designer exactly the way it would appear at run time. Is it possible and, if so, how can do it?

Here is what I tried (only relevant parts of the code):

```
Public Class StyledButton : Inherits Button      
  Private p_fEnabled As Boolean

  <DefaultValue(True)>
  Public Shadows Property Enabled As Boolean
    Get
      Return p_fEnabled
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
      p_fEnabled = value
      MyBase.Enabled = value
      UpdateVisualStyle()
    End Set
  End Property

  Private Sub UpdateVisualStyle()
    If Me.Enabled Then
      'set enabled appearance
    Else
      'set disabled appearance
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you left out the best part... the set enabled/disabled proc needs to eventually invoke Paint usually via Invalidate

Comment: @Plutonix: I tried to call `Me.Invalidate()` at the end of `UpdateVisualStyle`, also tried `Me.Refresh()`. Still, no change of behavior at design time. Any other ideas?

Comment: Controls are always Enabled in the designer.  Just as setting Visible to False does not actually hide a control from US, the enabled state is not changed.  They also do not `glow` when VisualStyles are enabled when the mouse is over them.  Some props are just RT only.  You might also have to change `UseVisualStyleBackColor` if VisualStyles are active.  (the prop setter is not called in the IDE - use OnEnableChanged to see)

Comment: @Plutonix: I know this. That's why I created my own Enabled property which Shadows the original Enabled property. So in theory, designer should start using the new property, showing Enabled and Disabled appearance properly.

Comment: change the name to `neoEnabled` and it will work (w/ Invalidate)

Comment: @Plutonix: It works now - thank you. You can post this as an answer, also if you know why it did not work with a shadowed property, please share your knowledge. `UseVisualStyleBackColor` seems to be assigned automatically when BackColor is set, so no need to force it.

Comment: I tried to do something with VisualStyles, but nothing seems to work in the IDE...no property changed watcher, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shadowed property does work as designed at runtime, just not in the IDE. You would not want to loose controls which are `Visible = False`, and you would want to drill into Button events even when `Enabled = False`.  Since the IDE has no intention of drawing a disabled control, there is no reason for it to invoke Invalidate when you change the property.

Since it works at runtime, trick it in the designer to use another property which looks like the original:

```
<Browsable(False), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never),
          EditorBrowsable(False)>
Public Shadows Property Enabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return neoEnabled
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        neoEnabled = value
    End Set
End Property
```

A new property, with the right name for the IDE.

```
<DisplayName("Enabled")>
Public Property neoEnabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return p_fEnabled
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)

        p_fEnabled = value
        UpdateVisualStyle()
        MyBase.Enabled = p_fEnabled

    End Set
End Property
```

Sadly, both `Enabled` and `neoEnabled` will be offered by Intellisense in code, but since they both do the same thing, its not a big deal.  test code:

```
Private Sub UpdateVisualStyle()
    If p_fEnabled Then
        ' other interesting stuff
        MyBase.BackColor = Color.Lime
    Else
        MyBase.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    End If

    MyBase.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

You have probably wrestled with it more that I, and come up with a cleaner implementation.

---

This persists the BackColor associated with `neoEnabled` state:

```
'
'StyledButton1
'
Me.StyledButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
Me.StyledButton1.Enabled = False
Me.StyledButton1.neoEnabled = False
```

versus

```
Me.StyledButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime
Me.StyledButton1.Enabled = False
Me.StyledButton1.neoEnabled = True
```

Comment: This isn't okay, the change you make to BackColor will be persisted.  It will always look disabled at runtime.

Comment: I decided to keep the custom property name (`EnabledCustom`) and hide the original `Enabled`. This way the person looking for Enabled will still find it, and will know what it is (a custom implementation of `Enabled` property). +1 and accepting.

Comment: it effectively destroys BackColor as an independent property, but it is persisted based on the new Enabled property.  "neoEnabled" was tongue in cheek.

Comment: @Plutonix: In my implementation there is a new property called BackColorEnabled, and also ForeColorEnabled, while the original properties BackColor and ForeColor are hidden. Disabled appearance is hard coded to grey on grey. I think the proper solution would be creating a custom designer class, which renders controls in their disabled state, but it looks too complicated for this task (considering the workaround). I will put a link here, if anyone's interested: [How to: Extend the Appearance and Behavior of Controls in Design Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms171820.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

I'll explain why it behaves this way.  A control behaves a lot at design time as it does at runtime.  It provides the strong WYSIWYG support in the Winforms designer.  But certain properties are very awkward at design time, you would not actually want the Visible property to take effect for example.  Pretty important that the control remains visible even though you set Visible to *False* in the Properties Window.

This is a core role of the *designer* for a control.  It intercepts these kind of difficult properties and emulates them.  Showing the *intended* value in the property grid but not actually passing them on to the control's property setter.

The *Enabled* property fits this category.  If it weren't intercepted then the control couldn't be selected anymore.  Other ones are ContextMenu, AllowDrop, Location for UserControl and Form, etcetera.   Your Shadows replacement doesn't fool the designer, it uses Reflection to find properties by name.  So your property doesn't have any effect, your property setter simply never gets called.

You can only truly get this by overriding OnPaint() for the control so you can display a different color at design time.  And a custom designer to poke it.  A significant hang-up however is that it isn't simple to replace the renderer for the button, the one that implements the OnPaint() method.  Microsoft decided to make the renderers *internal*, you can't override them.

Way too much trouble, I recommend you pass this up.

Comment: +1. Thanks Hans, very nice explanation. This part answers my question: `it uses Reflection to find properties by name`. Though I would prefer the designer to show some hint for disabled controls as well as for hidden controls (`Visible = False`). Could have been a border of some special color and/or pattern, an overlay with special background, and 50% opacity etc. But I guess Microsoft don't see it as I see it. :) In my current program disabled button means a feature is "not implemented, but can be implemented". Because it's a tool for developers, disabled state serves as an extension point.